# Need To Make Minor Change To REST API Response

Tags: api, rest

I have a website with information contained in several mySQL tables. This info is accessible via a REST API. I need to make a small change to this by adding two more fields to the response. But, this API was written by a firm that now has long lead times for modifications.

Is there a way I can make these changes myself or does the original developer need to do this? I have the ability & knowledge to make changes to the website itself and I have done many of these over the years, but I'm not familiar with API programming. Where do I find the code on the server that runs the API? Is this generally editable or is it 'wrapped' in a DLL? Or, am I completely off base?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not completely off the base. In order to make any changes to the REST API, an access to the source code of API will be required. The code can be located to server where the API is hosted.
Generally it is editable and not wrapped in a DLL.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil! I've looked all over for that code, but I can't see it anywhere. Any idea what I should be looking for or where I should be looking?

Comment: I think I answered my own question...Apparently,  the API code is hosted somewhere other than my local server.

Comment: it it is not available on your local server than it may be hosted somewhere on cloud or remote server. to check location of api code you can check with hosting provider that developed the api.